# Select Default Filter in BDCM File

Tags: filter, bcs, external-content-type, bdc-model, external-data-column

When working with Business Connectivity Services (BCS) and Business Data Connectivity Model (BDCM) files, does anyone know in the code where to set the "default" Filter and hide the  option?

Right now, it defaults to "select filter" which seems to search everything, but I want to set the default to one of the other search scopes.

[image]